# Can you help review the answers on this popular question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have a question that at the time of writing has over 30 answers (including deleted ones):

[Is there any job that can't be automated?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57989/is-there-any-job-that-cant-be-automated)

With that sort of scale it's likely that excellent answers are being ignored, ones that can be improved are not being improved, and bad answers are not being dealt with.

I'd just like to ask everyone who has time to scan through all the answers on this question (not just the top few) and give them all the attention they deserve.

Comment: All your attention seems to have gotten it put on hold.

Comment: @kingledion Hmm. I don't fully agree with the hold, it seems reasonably objective. It's borderline enough that I'm not going to mod hammer it open but if you wanted to start a meta discussion and see if people think it should be open or closed that would be fine by me :)

Comment: I already voted to reopen it. Stack Exchange is supposed to be a democracy, and if 16k viewers think it is interesting, who are 5 moderators to close it?

Comment: If the question breaches guidelines then they are correct to close it, no matter how popular. Keep in mind that closing doesn't need moderators (we have a diamond next to our name), it just needs any high reputation users.